# Foreign key constraint when using drop down in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using a drop down box with a foreign key relationship. I have got the drop down filling in the correct values but the only problem is when I add a user there is a foreign key constraint. But I can make users if I just use the normal input box and type an id that exists in the other table.
For example when I enter the id with this in my add.ctp, it works:

```
echo $this->Form->input('location');
```

but when I use this it doesn't

```
echo $this->Form->input('location_id', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $CompanyLocations));
```

This is my add function in my UsersController

```
public function add()
{
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
$this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $CompanyLocations= $this->Users->CompanyLocations->find('list'); 
    $this->set(compact('CompanyLocations'));
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
```

This is in my UsersTable

```
    $this->belongsTo('CompanyLocations');
```

and my CompanyLocationsTable

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('company_locations');
    $this->displayField('location_name');
    $this->primaryKey('location_id');

    $this->belongsTo('Locations', [
        'foreignKey' => 'location_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

and my MySQL code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS southpac_team.company_locations (
location_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
location_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (location_id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS southpac_team.users ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS southpac_team.users (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
department INT NULL,
mobile VARCHAR(255) NULL,
email VARCHAR(255) NULL,
extension INT NULL,
lame_number INT NULL,
spa_auth_number VARCHAR(15) NULL,
creation_date DATE NULL,
picture VARCHAR(255) NULL,
employed TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
location INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
INDEX get location_idx (location ASC),
CONSTRAINT get location
FOREIGN KEY (location)
REFERENCES southpac_team.company_locations(location_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Do you mean there is no location_id set as values for dropdown item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Naming conventions

You are not following the naming conventions, by default the foreign key name for a `belongsTo` association is the singular underscored variant of the association alias, postfixed with `_id` so in the case of `CompanyLocations` that would be `company_location_id`, not just `location`.

```
echo $this->Form->input('company_location_id');
```

Also the variable holding the list should use camel casing, then you don't even need to specify it via the options argument:

```
$companyLocations= $this->Users->CompanyLocations->find('list'); 
$this->set(compact('companyLocations'));
```

### Change the association defaults

If you are working with a legacy database that you cannot modify, then you need to configure CakePHP accordingly, ie specify the custom foreign key via the options argument of `Table::belongsTo()`.

```
$this->belongsTo('CompanyLocations', [
    'foreignKey' => 'location'
]);
```

### Bake gets confused

The `belongsTo` association in `CompanyLocationsTable` looks fishy too, unless you really have a `LocationsTable` that should be associated with `CompanyLocationsTable` via:

```
company_locations.location_id > locations.primary_key
```

I guess you've created the model via bake, which treated `location_id` as a foreign key since it matches the default foreign key naming scheme for a `belongsTo` association.

### See also

- **[Cookbook > CakePHP at a Glance > Conventions > Model and Database Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > BelongsTo Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Form Controls](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-form-controls)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Inputs for Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs)**

Comment: Thank you so much all I had to do was add change department in the users table to company_department_id. I'm new to php and cakephp so didn't really know how it worked so thanks a lot it really helped!